# Wordpress Soeldad meta info hide

Tags: wordpress

Im working on my blog in WP. Im using soeldad theme. Im trying to hide info about who wrote article (in my situation - by admin [acctualy "przez" admin, przez means by]). I did it in single post but still has it on main page.

Here is site url: https://wycinki.com.pl/

And ss, where I tic what I want to hide.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that in your css:

```
.grid-post-box-meta span.author-italic {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Thomas. Its working and its also something new for me.

Comment: Perfect, do not forget to upvote and mark this answer as accepted to help others finding this answer.